# Unknown attribute errors thrown by Rspec when trying to test a nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have built an application based on the Hartl course - up to and including section 9.2 (authentication). From there I have tried to extend the functionality by adding in an Organization model. Initially I tried using the scaffold generate command line function, decided it had built too much, rolled it back and then built it by hand. I believe in this mess I may have screwed up my migrations (see below). I'm using Rails v4.1.1, Rspec 3.0.0 and Capybara 2.2.0 - all databases are postgres.

An Organization can have_many users, whereas each User belongs_to only one Organization.

I should note that using the dev environment on my own machine, I have the field for Organization working correctly during a user sign up - it creates a new user, I can view both organization and user pages correctly, and there are no errors thrown in the performance of the app. My issues begin when I'm testing using the Rspec tests - throwing a range of errors like this:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
   can't write unknown attribute 'organization_id'
```

My models:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token, :create_organization
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}

  def create_organization
    self.organization = Organization.create(:organization_name => Organization.organization_name) unless self.organization.present?
  end
```

My Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization do
    organization_name "Orgname"
  end
  factory :user do
    association :organization
    name "A Name"
    email "name@example.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

An example Rspec test suite:

```
describe "edit" do
  let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization) }
  let(:login) { FactoryGirl.create(:login,
                                   :organization => organization,
                                   :user => FactoryGirl.create(:user)) }
  before do
    sign_in login
    visit edit_user_path (user)
  end
```

My schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140619041326) do

  create_table "organizations", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string "organization_name"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.integer "organization_id"
    t.string "remember_token"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["organization_id"], name: "index_users_on_organization_id", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token", using: :btree

end
```

It may be worth noting here that when I first started running the tests I was using the Rspec version recommended in Hartl's book - meaning I had to force through changes from the development DB to the test DB using the bin/rake dg:migrate RAILS_ENV=test command line function. Every time I ran this, my schema.rb file (as posted above) would lose the line

`t.integer "organization_id"`

and I'd have to rake the db to get it working again.

I realise there's a lot of info here, and that my questions are probably pretty dumb (I'm new to the language and framework and this is my first app) but it's driving me mad. I've spent the past week trying to find out why the tests are broken when the actual app itself is working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've found the issue - apparently Rails 4 doesn't automatically update the schema using `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` in spec_helper - instead you still need to use "rake db:test:prepare".

However whilst this has rid me of some errors, I still get 3 main errors: 

1.)It doesn't like my factory "login" (I was copying other code which seemed to suggest this would work)

2.) On the user pages rspec tests it cannot find the field "Orgnaization name" 

3.) It says the method "organization_name" is undefined for the "create_organization" function listed above

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no factory for `:login`  ... and I think that the sign_in method wants to pass in a user object.

So change your `let(:login)` statement to...

```
let(:login) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :organization => organization) }
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved this by adding a trait to the user factory, and passing both a new user and the trait. Would your method be better or should I just leave my code as-is?

Answer (score 0):

Your `before_create` method `create_organization` the following line...

```
  self.organization = Organization.create(:organization_name => Organization.organization_name) unless self.organization.present?
```

You're referencing a class (not object) method when you do `Organization.organization_name` and no such class method exists.

You could create it in the `Organization` model... it could be some default value...

```
def self.organization_name
  "Default Organization Name"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. My intention with that create_organization code was to ensure that anyone signing up for an account where there is an existing organization would belong to that organization (rather than duplicate it). Would setting a default value have any negative consequences? Or is there a better way to achieve my objective without this create_organization code?

Comment: As it is, if an organization has already been assigned to the User before calling create, it will behave as expected.  Are you saying that if no organization was assigned but there is already at least one organization in the organizations table, you want to use whatever is the first record in the organizations table?

Comment: No, I was just concerned that this would let people sign up without including an organization name, then be stuck as part of a group using "Default Org Name" instead. At the moment that will have no impact, but eventually I want the first user to sign up for any organization to be the admin user, and to be able to run reports across the whole user base. If people who omit an organization name can still sign up it would create a problem.

Comment: Ok well the code `Organization.organization_name` is not right as there's no such class method.  It sounds like as part of the sign up progess the user can enter an organization name?  And you want to use that to build the organization record?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A (brand new) user coming to the site is signing up both his own user name as well as the organization name to which he will belong. Subsequent users trying to sign up for the same organization will be sent to a queue for the first user to approve (first user will be the admin eventually). The point in that code was to try and prevent multiple organizations with the same name arising.